# JQuery Ajax Hangs IE11

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-11

This ajax call makes IE11 and css animations freeze. Mozilla and Chrome are fine. Not only this one is problematic, I put it just as an example. Here are several workarounds those I've tried so far:

-Disabled cache. I disabled it from server.,

-Tried setTimeout trick,

-Removed nested functions. Event just the .html() method didn't work alone.

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
        url: "accordion.php?cat="+aid,
        async: true,
        success: function (html) {
                $("#accordion").animate({ right: "140%"},500, function () {
                  $(this).css("right","-25%", $(this).hide(1, function() {
                    $(this).html(html).show(1, function() {
                      $(this).animate({right: "100%"},1000),$ajaxloading.fadeOut("slow")})}));});}})
```

Comment: Do the functions in `success` function freeze the browser if you put them out of AJAX(with static `html` string)?

Comment: Actually it's a clever suggestion but it won't be the same. It's a php ajax sending variables. It makes me curious if it hangs during php writing. But, anyway... I'll give it a try with some other html string and let you know the result.

Comment: `function myAjax(html){$("#accordion").animate({ right: "140%"},500, function () {$(this).css("right","-25%", $(this).hide(1, function() {$(this).html(html).show(1, function() {$(this).animate({right: "100%"},1000),$loading.fadeOut("slow")})}));});}
}});

htm:"<foo><bar>Do Jo</bar></foo>";myAjax(htm);
`

This works supersmooth. I tried with a big table and had no problem. I am linking some other .js file in the accordion.php. Maybe it is because IE is trying to initialize those scripts.

Comment: Still looks strange. One other test case maybe to use exact `action.php` result as a parameter to your `myAjax()` function without using AJAX again (`htm: "action.php output, write yourself"`). If it freezes again, then it is not about AJAX but ie I guess.

Comment: Yeah, also long php writings causes the hang. Briefly, js initilizing and long php calls cause hangs in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The problem is Active Content filtering feature of IE. My php includes script resources linked to .js files. During the writing of php, IE hangs when it comes to those lines. It is a Jquery accordion and needs several js'es to operate. I deleted script tags and was working fine. I think I'll move those tag to main page and they will be loaded and run always even they are not needed; which is not my first preference.